# How to use azure application gateway for outbound traffic of a vnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

I am looking for a way to expose a virtual networks (VNET) outbound IP in Azure to use a static outbound IP without attaching a public facing network interface directly to a specific Virtual Machine in that network. We thought an application gateway would be a potential solution but can't find how it works.

Reasoning behind this is that Azure offers some services that are not yet supporting VNet integration and only allow IP Whitelistings. We don't want to expose our VNET, only through an Application Gateway. But if a machine from within a VNET connects to the outside, it won't have a static IP (only a potential range) to do so and thus it's failing due to IP Whitelisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you only want to have an outbound internet connectivity for your VNET, you can try Azure NAT Gateway (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway-resource). NAT gateway resources are part of Virtual Network NAT and provide outbound Internet connectivity for one or more subnets of a virtual network. Once you have it's up, you can whitelist NAT Gateway's public IP.